# NPV total will be using the calculation in Microsoft Excel

Tags: .net

The NPV total will be using the calculation in Microsoft Excel.

Specifically: **Year 1 + NPV(0.08,Year2+0,Year3+0,Year4+0,Year5+0)** for the Cashflow Analysis section, using the NET row for the values and the values in the Lease row for the Lease section of Buy Versus Lease.

I used jquery to display the total:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    //iterate through each textboxes and add keyup
    //handler to trigger sum event
    $(".txBxCashFlowNetYear1").each(function () {

        $(this).keyup(function () {
            alert();
            calculateSum();
        });
    });

});

function calculateSum() {

    var sum = 0;
    //iterate through each textboxes and add the values
    $(".txBxCashFlowNetYear1").each(function () {

        //add only if the value is number
        if (!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length != 0) {
            sum += parseFloat(this.value);
        }

    });
    //.toFixed() method will roundoff the final sum to 2 decimal places
    $("#txBxCashF
```